# How to Subtract textbox value with datagridview column..VB

Tags: vb.net

I need help for my vb project. Last day I created stock database

The database have 2 columns `Item Name` and `Quantity`

In my form I have two textboxes same as database and a button

when button press

- if my "Itemname textbox" match with database column `itemname` then "Quantity Textbox" subtract with "Quantity column"
- if match with database "itemname column"[2] the column2 quantity subtract with "Quantitytextbox"

Here's my Code it works but it's lengthy:

```
If itemname.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = CDbl(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value) - CDbl(quantity.Text)
            MsgBox("Data Saved SuccessFully")
            quantity.Text = ""
            itemname.Text = ""

        ElseIf itemname.text = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = CDbl(quantity.Text) - CDbl(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value)
            MsgBox("Data Saved SuccessFully")
            quantity = ""
            itemname.Text = ""

        ElseIf itemname.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(0).Value Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value = CDbl(quantity.Text) - CDbl(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value)
            MsgBox("Data Saved SuccessFully")
            quantity = ""
            itemname.Text = ""


        ElseIf itemname.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(0).Value Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value = CDbl(quantity.Text) - CDbl(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value)
            MsgBox("Data Saved SuccessFully")
            quantity.Text = ""
            itemname.Text = ""

          endif
end sub
```

And so on.......

PLEASE HELP ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `For...Next` loop to go through the rows:

```
 Dim intRow As Integer
 'loop through the rows, looking for a matching record
 For intRow = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
   If itemname.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(intRow).Cells(0).Value Then
     Me.DataGridView1.Rows(intRow).Cells(1).Value = CDbl(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(intRow).Cells(1).Value) - CDbl(quantity.Text)
     MsgBox("Data Saved SuccessFully")
     quantity.Text = ""
     itemname.Text = ""
     Exit For 'exit the loop
   End If
 Next intRow
```

The variable `intRow` is used instead of typing out each row number.