# Datagridview subtract quantity when textbox texts are same C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

i am trying to code a accounting software.
My problem is, i need to subtract quantity values if texts are same with between datagridview  and textbox. Let me explain with picture. If the textbox texts which is marked with red circle are same then i need to subtract the green marked textbox text value from datagridview's quantity value.
[image]

i've checked this before [How to Subtract textbox value with datagridview column..VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418701/how-to-subtract-textbox-value-with-datagridview-column-vb)

but i can't apply it to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the sample click function

[image]

Then select the row in the datagridview from which you want to subtract,
And only then subtract the textbox.

This line of code selects the value in the first column of the clicked line:

```
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvOrder.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```